# Is there a way to see raw string values using SQL / presto SQL / athena?

Tags: encoding, presto, amazon-athena

Edit after asked to better specify my need:

**TL;DR:** How  to show whitespace escaped characters (such as `/r`) in the Athena console when performing a query? So this: `"abcdef/r"` instead of this `"abcdef "`.

I have a dataset with a column that contains some strings of variable length, all of them with a trailing whitespace.

Now, since I had analyzed this data before, using python, I know that this whitespace is a `\r`; however, if in Athena I `SELECT my_column`, it obviously doesn't show the escaped whitespace.

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve:

```
my_column |  ..
----------+--------
 abcdef\r |  ..
 ghijkl\r |  ..
```

What I'm getting instead:

```
my_column |  ..
----------+--------
  abcdef  |  ..
  ghijkl  |  ..
```

If you're asking why would I want that, it's just to avoid having to parse this data through python if I ever incur in this situation again, so that I can immediately know if there's any weird escaped characters in my strings.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to _show_ \r or have this in _predicate_ (eg LIKE)?

Comment: Do you want to see it in the Athena web console? The characters are there (if you query it to Python) just not showing.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I want to be able to display them in the Athena console as '/r' instead of a generic white space, which could be anything.